# How to refer to HTML table cell by row, col index in jQuery - cell(3,4)

Tags: html, jquery, dom, html-table

I'm new to jQuery. I can extract column and row number from the active cell (see below), but I cannot find the way to refer to the tables's cell in jQuery, using row and column index like in other languages (for example in Python's Pandas).

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var colIndex = $(this).closest("td").index();
  var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  //do something here
})
```

Is it possible to refer to cell by using row and column index in jQuery?

This is the best solution I've found online, but it doesn't let me pass variables for row and column number. I think I'm getting closer, but I am not sure if this is the bests approach.

Example: Cell(3,3) for cell in 3rd row and 3rd column:

```
var cell = $('table').find('tr:eq(3)').find('td:eq(3)')
```

This would make life much easier when working with tables. Could you kindly advise?

Comment: You first say "cannot find the way to refer to the tables's cell in jQuery", and at the end you give a possible way to do just that? What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I think I didn't realise I can concatenate variables to pass index for row and column to this equation. Below There is answer with 2 interesting methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery to do this. It is easier to pick up the DOM table element, and use its `rows` and nested `cells` property:

```js
let $td = $($("table").get(0).rows[1].cells[2]);
console.log($td.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for. Looks very simple and concise! Thanks you! --                 
     var cell = $(  $('table').get(0).rows[ row_no ].cells[ col_no ]  )

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate variables into the `:eq()` part of the selector:

```
var cell = $('table').find('tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').find('td:eq('+ colIndex + ')')
```

Or a bit simpler is use `eq()` method

```
var cell = $('table tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex)
```

Comment: This can give unreliable results when tables have nested tables.

Comment: Thanks, I have simple, single table, but this is great point. I would have thought jQuery would have something like a cell object but it doesn't. With nested table I think we would need to give each table id or assign class?

Comment: `children()` instead of `find()` is one possibility as it would not include nested table rows and you would want to use a more specific selector than `'table'`

Comment: Still "table tr" can match "table tr td table tr".

Comment: @trincot sure but that's why i mentioned using children or children selector

Comment: Oh OK, I read "instead of `find()`." Note that `tr` are not children of `table`, but of `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot`...

Comment: Thanks for those comments, this is a bit beyond my application. But Iv'e learned a lot from both of you.